# Get facebook friends in 2.0 (only ones using app) not working for sandbox app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm requesting friends list in my app (an app that has not been yet approved) for testing. One of my coworkers is added to the developing role and he has executed the app in his android device and accepted the application. The application is listed under games in his profile.

I have done the same. I have executed the app in my device and accepted the permissions (I'm administrator in roles). Me and my coworker are friends on facebook.

The problem is that when I run /me/friends in the graph api explorer I always get an empty array. I know facebook changed the friends thing to only show friends using same app but my coworker and me are friends and we can't see each other.

We have spent almost all day on this if anyone could help I would really apreciate it.

More info:

I have noticed something: There's a combo in the Graph API Explorer where you can select the Application. If I select my application (the one I will put into production later) and run the query nothing is returned. But If I select a test application I have just created it works ok (If I select as application "Graph API explorer" it works too. Could anybody guess what is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did both users grant `user_friends` permission?

Comment: Yes, when they log in.

Comment: I have added some more information under "More info" to the problem